# Generic "An error occurred submitting the question"

Tags: support, error-message

No weird formatting, not particularly long. 4 tags

It is a question that is similar to many other ones on Stack Overflow (SSIS package only intermittently writing to Excel destination, despite always claiming success), but I have reviewed all the other posts, and my question is distinct.

I seem to have reputation points... why else would this get blocked?

[image: My question]

Comment: Chances are, you have some local web filter / proxy / whatever that hates SQL and silently kills the attempt to post before it ever hits our server. Not kidding. Check out the "related" sidebar...

Comment: Hm. I ask SQL Server questions on SO pretty frequently from this computer, but I suppose corporate policy could have change. I'll try masking the SQL.

Comment: That was it! I added underscores to all the SQL terms, and the question posted. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Shog9 Shouldn't that be prevented by the fact that Stack Overflow is using HTTPS now?

Comment: @KonradRudolph some corporate web filters transparently MITM https sessions, their CA is installed on all clients and they create certs on the fly :-( Don't know whether this is the case but... it's actually possible.

Comment: @Sklivvz “security”.